How to set a default value of 1 year from now for expire_at in Laravel migrations?
I am creating fields for a table in Laravel. I want to create a expire_at column using $table->timestamps() but set a default date of 1 year from now.
Currently, I am trying the following:
$table->timestamps('expire_at')->default('1 year from now');

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

From Laravel timestamps() doesn't create CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it seems that something like $table->timestamp('expire_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR')); should do the trick

You can use Carbon (Recommended)
$table->timestamp('expire_at')->default(now()->addYear());


This would set the default value of the expire_at column to 2024-12-09 08:29:23, i.e. the static value from when this migration is run (using "now" as an example). If you want the default to be 1 year from the current date/time when a record is inserted, then the comment to the main question is correct, not this.
